# Django: Dynamic inline forms with filter upon user selection

Tags: python, django, forms, inline-formset

I have created these models:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=200)code here

class Monitor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, related_name='monitors')

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)

class ServiceMonitors(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    monitors = models.ManyToManyField(Monitor)
```

These models represent a company that offer many services to students. Monitors that work for this company are assigned to students who need the service they offer. A monitor can offer many services and have many students for every one of them. Also, a student can have many services and monitors.

Let's suppose the we have 3 services, s1, s2 and s3. When we create a new Monitor we assign him/her some of these services, let's say s1 and s3. Then, when we create a new Student, we should be able to choose which services and monitors the student will have.

My problem here is that I need a form to create the student (name, phone, etc...) that allows me to:

1. Select a service from a dropdown control
2. Once a service is selected, the form must show the Monitors that offer that service, so I can choose one or more of them (checkboxes).
3. A + button to create/show a new form to repeat the process, so I
   can choose a new service and the related Monitors.

I'm very new to Django. I've been able to create an inline form in the user creation form, but i'm stuck here. I have now a dropdown control to select a service, and a ModelMultipleChoiceField with a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget which shows all Monitors. From here I need to know how to filter these Monitors when the user selects a service, and how to add new forms to select new services/monitors.

Answer (score 2):

This likely can not be managed within the Django forms framework which is very limited in functionality. It allows you to use a filtered queryset for selections in a ModelChoiceDropDown (I think that's the name) but filtering after a selection isn't possible this way. Django's forms are generated and sent as HTML which can not be made to filter without many modifications.

The way you would likely do this is to set up a REST interface (See Django Rest Framework or Django-Tastypie) and link your dropdowns to that using a front end framework of your choosing (I prefer Backbone.js, but there are many options). The idea being that once you select a service the subsequent dropdowns will add a filter to their requests to only show the Monitors that offer that service.

If you wish to keep using Django Forms you can, but you'll need to extend the default fields to get this sort of functionality.

This is a fairly big rabbit hole and I don't have any resources off the cuff to point you toward. But reading up about REST interfaces is a good start.

Comment: Thank you Don, I think I'll try this with custom forms and some JS. Will try to show all services as checkboxes and show related monitors when the user selects a service. This way I can send all information filtered to the client side.